# Go get error: cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

Tags: go, package, libraries

I have been receiving a strange error when trying to import external libraries/packages in Go when running any go get command I get the forllowing error

```
    # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

I have tried updating mingw

```
 mingw-get update
```

but I still get the same error, what can I do to fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: You use 64-bit Go, so you have to install 64-bit (mingw-w64) for cgo.